# Jquery - Click event on resize() not work properly

Tags: jquery, resize, jquery-click-event

I have a problem with jquery's resize() method and click event: in the example below, resizing the window, the click event only works in a some pixels. For example, resizing width of window one pixel at a time will work some times yes some times not. Why this behavior?
if I take the click event out of my code, toggleClass works fine for every pixel.
I have tried with both firefox and chrome.

**EDIT:** I need the click to work only when the window width is resized below a given size.

jquery:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).resize(function() {
      if ($(window).width() < 1000) {
        $(".button").click(function() {
          $("#box").toggleClass("open");
        });  
      }
    });
  });
```

css:

```
#box {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: red;
}

#box.open {
  background-color: green;
}
```

html:

```
<body>
  <div id="box"></div>
  <button class="button">Click</button>
</body>
```

[Example on Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/VinzClortho/6vu0gx4b/3/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you're adding multiple click events every time the window is resized, so after a few resizes, one single click will `toggleClass`, `toggleClass`, `toggleClass`... times how many pixels window was resized.

```
$(window).resize(function() {
  // Every time window resize do this:

  // Add new click event
  $(".button").click(function() {
    $("#box").toggleClass("open");
  });  
});
```

-- Edit --
If it's just for a specific window size, you don't really need the `resize` part.
You can just check the window size on every click.
This should be enough:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".button").click(function() {
    if ($(window).width() < 1000) {
      $("#box").toggleClass("open");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#box {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: red;
}

#box.open {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="box"></div>
<button class="button">Click</button>
```

Comment: No, forgive me if I have not been clear. I used resize() because I need the click to work only under a given size. To simplify the example I removed `if ($ (window).width() <1000)`. I updated the question, I hope it is clearer now.

Comment: @VinzClortho No problem. In that case, you don't need the `resize` part. I have updated the answer.

Comment: You're right, I was focusing too much on resize() because I didn't understand its conflict with click event. In fact, I didn't need it. Thanks.